# Stack Overflow user name changed on its own

Tags: support

Today I logged into stack overflow and my name had changed from Michellejs to user223250. I went to change it back and I got a message saying I can only change it once every 30 days. Is there anyway I can fix this?

Comment: Maybe your account was merged? Googling Michellejs finds a different user that no longer exists. http://stackoverflow.com/users/1104109/michellejs

Comment: I think it may have been merged. I created an account on meta and tried to link it but I couldn't figure out how. So I'm guessing it merged on its own but I don't really understand what changed. I had been planning on learning how to properly link to the two but I hadn't had time yet. But I guess now it has been done for me. I guess not being able to fix my username for another month is no big deal. I just suspect people are more likely to be friendly when you have an actual user name as opposed to a default number.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yep, this was a result of a merge. I remember approving it yesterday, though I don't recall the exact specifics anymore.

Basically, you ended up with two profiles and our systems flagged them for a merge but it required human intervention to make sure the profiles matched up.

I'm surprised that merging blocks you from changing your name again, though. Still, I'm glad you have it all resolved now. :)